# Check for NULL wait time for Coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code. It works fine. User makes input from UI button - how long he wants to wait in coroutine(3,5,tcs). But the problem is if user forgot to enter time to wait from UI button, then my code under "do something" will not being executed. 
I tried to do next logic:

if  waitingTime.text is Null, 
then use Default time == 3.0f
else: use time user has entered

But my code stopped working at all. Do you have any idea how to implement correctly? Thanks for suggestions!

```
public InputField waitingTime;  // input from user. 


    public void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Routine());

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        StopCoroutine(Routine());
    }


    IEnumerator Routine() 
    {
        for (;;) {

            float t = float.Parse (waitingTime.text);
            Debug.LogWarning ("Wait for: " + t + "sec");

            // Do something 

        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry, i missed in Routine to return : yield return new WaitForSeconds (t);

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of your code is kinda unclear, so having a wider view on your goals would be of great help to provide a solution. Anyway, I think this should fix a few issues...

```
while (true) // hey, we are gentlemen after all...
{
    Single t;

    if (!Single.TryParse(waitingTime.text, out t))
        t = 3.0f;

    Debug.LogWarning("Waiting for " + t.ToString() + "seconds...");

    // Do something
}
```

Comment: `Sleep` is for multithreading. Coroutines use [`yield`](https://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html). Coroutines are not threads.

Comment: i am yield returning time, which User inputs from UI input field. but, what if user do not want or forget to input, then use as time value default . I am trying to get frame update not every sec, instead every T times, when user will enter. If input is missing, then capture frames every sec.